# Is there a way to use apply as well in this question?

Tags: r

Create a function, kdice(n, k), that simulates n rolls of k dice. The result should be the sum of the k rolls. For example, if k = 2 and the results of two rolls are 3 and 4, kdice should return 7. [Hint: you could use your dice(n) function as part of the kdice code.

This is what I've done. I am not sure if I did the right thing.

```
kdice = function(n, k){
  # Your code here
  kdice = rep(0, k)
  for(i in 1:k){
    k = sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE)
    print(sum(k))
    }
}
kdice(5, 4)
```

Comment: E.g. `kdice <- function(n, k) sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) sum(sample(1:6, k, replace = TRUE)))`.

Comment: In your question you first talk about k dice and later about k rolls. This is confusing and you should revise it.